# Unable to read object property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, foreach

I'm trying to render a page with some details I get from a api call.

```
useEffect(() =>{
  getCards();
}, [])

  const [userCards, setCards] = useState([])

  const getCards = async (event) => {
  
    let token = localStorage.getItem("user");
  
    await api
      .get("/fetch-card-balance",
      {headers:{"token":`${token}`}})
      
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.success === false) {
          toast.error(response.data.message);
          setCards(false);
        } else if (response.data.success === true) {
          console.log(response.data.payload)
          setCards(response.data.payload)
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.error(err.response.data.message);
      });
  };
  console.log(userCards)
```

Here userCards is logged as

```
[
 {
  balance: 0.00,
  cifNumber: "0001111222",
  createdAt: "2021-08-03T12:19:51.000Z",
  first6: "123456",
  id: 1234,
  last4: "7890"
 },
 {
  balance: 20.00,
  cifNumber: "0002222333",
  createdAt: "2021-07-03T12:19:51.000Z",
  first6: "234567",
  id: 2345,
  last4: "8901"
 }
]
```

Then I try to use forEach to filter the properties I need

```
    const cardDetails = []
    userCards.forEach(option =>  cardDetails.push(
     {
      cardNumber: `${option.first6}******${option.last4}`,
      balance: `${option.balance}`
     }
    ))
```

But when I run

```
    console.log(cardDetails[0].balance)
```

I get  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'balance' of undefined". I've gone over it several times and the only conclusion I have is that I'm missing something that may not be so obvious. Could someone help point out what it is.

Comment: _"Could someone help point out what it is."_ - Not without an actual [mcve]. Where, when and how do you call `console.log(cardDetails[0].balance)`?

Comment: if you use async/await, it has no sense at all using then/catch. Stick to the first form, which is much more simple.

Comment: Try "console.log(cardDetails);" then get back to us with what it says.

Comment: @EmilKarlsson when I make that call, it returns the cardDetails array with the values I have pushed to it. That's why I confused as to why it throws an error when I try to call a property inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cardDetails[0].balance` will only work when there is at least one element in `cardDetails`. Otherwise getting the first element in the array yields `undefined`, causing your error message. Since you only fill the array after the API request returns, at least your first render will be done with an empty array.

An easy way to handle this would be checking for `if (cardDetails.length > 0)` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

const cardDetails = userCards.map(function(option) { return {cardNumber: `${option.first6}******${option.last4}`, balance: `${option.balance}`}});